# How to obtain file name from a GAE java blobstore upload

Tags: java, google-app-engine, upload, blobstore, datastore

To store file in GAE blobstore, I will create a jsp to upload

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post"     enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile"/> 
    <input type="file" name="myFile1"/>
    <input type="file" name="myFile2"/>
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, what is the normal way to link a file name with this

```
blobkey=blobs.get("myFile");
```

I want to map a filename with this blobkey, maybe in datastore for future use, so how to I upload a filename to let my servlet use, or how do I derive the file name (path can be omitted) from this blobkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it still uses the getParameter("filename") stuff to get to know extra info